# Can it be safe to share a var?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

My application has a class `ApplicationUsers` that has no mutable members. Upon creation of instances, it reads the entire user database (relatively small) into an immutable collection. It has a number of methods to query the data.

I am now faced with the problem of having to create new users (or modify some of their attributes). My current idea is to use an Akka actor that, at a high level, would look like this:

```
class UserActor extends Actor{
  var users = new ApplicationUsers

  def receive = {
    case GetUsers => sender ! users

    case SomeMutableOperation => {
      PerformTheChangeOnTheDatabase() // does not alter users (which is immutable)
      users = new ApplicationUsers // reads the database from scratch into a new immutable instance
    }
  }
}
```

Is this safe? My reasoning is that it should be: whenever `users` is changed by `SomeMutableOperation` any other threads making use of previous instances of `users` already have a handle to an older version, and should not be affected. Also, any `GetUsers` request will not be acted upon until a new instance is not safely constructed.

Is there anything I am missing? Is my construct safe?

UPDATE: I probably should be using [Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/agents.html) to do this, but the question is still holds: is the above safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it exactly right: have immutable data types and reference them via `var` within the actor. This way you can freely share the data and mutability is confined to the actor. The only thing to watch out for is if you reference the `var` from a closure which is executed outside of the actor (e.g. in a `Future` transformation or a `Props` instance). In such a case you need to make a stack-local copy:

```scala
val currentUsers = users
other ? Process(users) recoverWith { case _ => backup ? Process(currentUsers) }
```

In the first case you just grab the value—which is fine—but asking the `backup` happens from a different thread, hence the need for `val currentUsers`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. You don't seem to need Agents here.

Comment: Thanks. I think agents would simplify my code (no need to create the above construct) and would also naturally separate the updating of the database from the updating of the `users` object, which in my case would be a better design.

Comment: I think the issue with agents is that they're only local to the node (jvm) you're running. You cannot pass them remotely to other nodes. This might generate issues when you want to scale out your system.